# How does work touchBegin on SKSpriteNode(SKNode) on SpriteKit?

Tags: button, swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan, touches

I use SpriteKit with Swift. A button I realized by override touchesBegin on SKSpriteNode. But I don't understand how it catch touch. Sometimes button not catch if over it has SKSpriteNode and sometimes on the contrary. Please explain to me.

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the issue you are having is touches not getting registered because of the .userInteractionEnabled setting. Make sure you do `sprite.userInteractionEnabled = true` because it defaults to false.